# Opscode Chef REST API invalid JSON

Tags: php, json, api, rest, chef-infra

I am trying to integrate with `Chef` via `PHP`

I used the library https://github.com/dv1r/php-chef to communicate with the `Hosted Enterprise Chef`. When I retrieve information from `Chef`, everything is fine. I can also delete clients and such.

The problem starts when I try to send data to the server. I always get the error "Invalid JSON".
The JSON that I am sending is valid according to http://jsonlint.com/ .

Does anybody know if i need to add and encoding type to the `json_encode()` inorder to fix this?

Code example:

```
    try{
        // Gets current data in Data-Bad `evns` Item `dev` (works)
        $res = $this->chef->get('/data/envs/dev');
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo("Exception: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
    // Alter Data
    $res->testtt = "testess";
    try{
        // Set's new data to Data-bag `envs` Item `dev` (FAILS)
        $ret = $this->chef->put("/data/envs/dev",$res);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        die("Exception: <br>".$e->getMessage());
    }
```

The interesting part of the library:

```
    // json encode data
    if ($data && !is_string($data)) {
        $data = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        $this->debug("data encoded to json: {$data}");
    }

    // sign the request
    $this->sign($endpoint, $method, $data, $header);
    $this->debug("request URL: {$url}");
    // initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

    // most people are using self-signed certs for chef, so its easiest to just
    // disable ssl verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    // add data to post and put requests
    if ($method == 'POST' || $method == 'PUT')
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    // execute
    $raw_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

If I missed some critical information, please comment and I will add.

Thank you.

EDIT: More debug info -

Raw Responses:

First call to the API (GET) `raw_response: {"name":"name","id":"dev"}`

Second call (PUT) `raw_response: {"error":["invalid JSON"]}`

Output of curl_getinfo($ch) [PUT]:

```
    Array
    (
        [url] => https://api.opscode.com/organizations/MY_ORG/data/envs/dev
        [content_type] => text/html
        [http_code] => 400
        [header_size] => 426
        [request_size] => 1665
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 1
        [total_time] => 0.175739
        [namelookup_time] => 2.0E-5
        [connect_time] => 0.02709
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.093261
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 26
        [speed_download] => 147
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 26
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.126115
        [redirect_time] => 0.049605
        [certinfo] => Array()
        [primary_ip] => 184.106.28.81
        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.50
        [local_port] => 33329
        [redirect_url] => 
        [request_header] => PUT /organizations/MY_ORG/data/envs/dev HTTP/1.1
    Host: api.opscode.com
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Chef-Version: 11.8.2
    X-Ops-Sign: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0
    X-Ops-UserId: USER
    X-Ops-Timestamp: 2014-05-07T13:39:55Z
    X-Ops-Content-Hash: qk8fSIReFrOMJ+Wk2y8yoe3EAgk=
    X-Ops-Authorization-1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    X-Ops-Authorization-2: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    X-Ops-Authorization-3: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    X-Ops-Authorization-4: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    X-Ops-Authorization-5: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    X-Ops-Authorization-6: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    )
```

Comment: `$data = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` have you played around with this line at all?  Changing the content type etc.?

Comment: yes, I've tried `JSON_HEX_TAG`,`JSON_HEX_APOS`,`JSON_HEX_QUOT`,`JSON_HEX_AMP`, and `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. (JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE seemed most logical to me.)

Comment: I'm thinking the error is misleading - perhaps your payload parses as JSON just fine, but it's not valid **Chef** JSON. Can you paste more debug output? What is the actual payload that you're sending? It'd also be helpful to see the response code from the request. API response codes for that method: http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#data-name-item

Comment: @Christopher Armstrong, I have added some INFO, but I am not sure how to check the request payload before it goes out. It is added to the request here `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: What are you trying to `PUT`? because you send headers that you're sending JSON, is that what you're really sending? try sending POST instead of PUT

Comment: yes, My data is JSON. I am trying to make this work: http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#data-name-item

Comment: Just an idea, since the JSON is being `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` try encoding the `testsss` as unicode as well with `iconv` etc.

Comment: @DvirLevy Try just dumping $data right after that line.

Comment: @Christopher Armstrong the encoding looks fine : `{"name":"name","id":"dev","testtt":"testess"}`

Comment: @DvirLevy yeah, I'm out of ideas. Have you tried the Chef mailing list? chef@lists.opscode.com - they're pretty receptive and will likely know the answer quickly

Answer (score 1):

The $res->testtt will be your main problem.

The 'magic' conversion is somehow buggy.
Cast to array and you'll be safest on what is done

i.e:

```
try{
    // Gets current data in Data-Bad `evns` Item `dev` (works)
    $res = (array) $this->chef->get('/data/envs/dev');
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo("Exception: ".$e->getMessage());
}
// Alter Data
$res['testtt'] = "testess";
try{
    // Set's new data to Data-bag `envs` Item `dev` (FAILS)
    $ret = $this->chef->put("/data/envs/dev",$res);
} catch (Exception $e){
    die("Exception: <br>".$e->getMessage());
}
```

Hope it will help.

Edit for a working exemple

```
<?php
 $envs = unserialize($_POST['envs']);
 foreach($_POST["datas"] as $env => $items) {
  ksort($items,SORT_NATURAL);
  $old = (array) $chef->get("/data/livraisons/".$env);
  $new = array_merge($old,$items);
  ksort($new,SORT_NATURAL);
  $chef->put("/data/livraisons/".$env,$new);
 }
?>
```

I hope it will help you figure it out ..

Warns:

1. I'm on an open source chef server (11.0.10), maybe that's the
   point (even if I doubt about it)
2. I'm using a slightly different
   version of the library which don't use constant with json_encode... see here: 
   https://github.com/jenssegers/php-chef

Comment: Still `Invalid JSON`.